# ionic build ios error unrecognized command

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Just testing a app. Trying to run the ios simulator. Got error message. Please help.

> $ ionic build ios Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   C:\Users\Johnson\desktop\ionic\todo\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
>   C:/Users/Johnson/desktop/ionic/todo add to body class: platform-ios
>   Running command: cmd "/s /c
>   "C:\Users\Johnson\desktop\ionic\todo\platforms\ios\cordova\build""
>   'C:\Users\Johnson\desktop\ionic\todo\platforms\ios\cordova\build' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file. ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 You may not have the required environment or
>   OS to build this project Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says

> You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

this refers to you not having iOS build tools (xcode) available on your machine. xcode is not available on windows machines.

You cannot build iOS apps on Windows machines. You may build for android, providing you have the android sdk + build tools installed.